# swiper.jsのloop時末端が途切れる

Tags: javascript, jquery

下記のように swiper クリック時に `slideTo` で 中央にフォーカスするようにしているんですが、始端や終端まで進めると途切れてしまいます。

マウスドラッグ or touchEvent を発生させると、また要素がクローンされるようなんですが、それをプログラムだけで完結出来る方法をご存知であれば知りたいです。
`swiper.slideTo()` の後 `swiper.update()` を追加したり、 option を色々試してみましたが梨の礫で。

```
let swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    slidesPerView: 4.9,
    spaceBetween: -1,
    loop: true,
    grabCursor: true,
    centeredSlides: true,
    uniqueNavElements: true,
});

swiper.on('click', function (){
    swiper.slideTo(swiper.clickedIndex);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。
`slideTo()` ではなく `slideToClickedSlide()` を使う事で途切れる事がなくなりました。